# Express.js API call is crashing my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm brand new to express.js and API calls, and I can't figure out why this is crashing my server? Essentially it will run the first time through and render the page, but then crash the server saying:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

`for (var i = 0; i < data.businesses.length; i++) {`

relevant section of code:

```
router.get('/:term/:radius/:lat/:lng', function (req, res) {

var yelp = require("yelp").createClient({
    consumer_key: "xxxx", 
    consumer_secret: "xxxx",
    token: "xxxx",
    token_secret: "xxxx"
});

yelp.search({
    term: req.params.term,
    radius_filter: req.params.radius,
    ll: req.params.lat + ',' + req.params.lng 
},
function (error, data) {

    var businessesArr = [];
    if (typeof data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.businesses.length; i++) {
            businessesArr.push({
                name: data.businesses[i].name,
                image_url: data.businesses[i].image_url
            });
        }
        res.render('selection', {
            businesses: businessesArr
        });
            // console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: In addition to the answer also note that `typeof data` returns the **string** `undefined` which evaluates to true. So you better check `if(error)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 if (typeof data) {
```

is always going to evaluate to true since it actually returns a string no matter what.

Replace it with something like:

```
   if (data && data.businesses) {
```

Comment: That helped! It loads the page, but then gives the the error below. I added a test and it looks like the anonymous function in the yelp.search is being ran twice with each request for the page.



```{ statusCode: 400,
    data: '{"error": {"text": "One or more parameters are invalid in request", "id": "INVALID_PARAMETER", "field": "ll"}}' }```

Comment: @th01 looks like what you're passing to `yelp.search` is not right for `ll`. You should also log out the values of everything you're sending to yelp on error. Then once you know what's breaking it you can check for that case before even bothering to make the `yelp.search` call.

Comment: I refactored my code and now it seems to be working without issue. I'm not sure why it was making a second request, but being able to get my error back help a lot in trying to troubleshoot.